# Get Buttons and store them in an array

Tags: c#, arrays, user-interface, button, unity-game-engine

So I've placed 6 UI buttons on my canvas which is "Tier 1" - "Tier 6"
I wanted to store all "Tier 1" - "Tier 6" in an array as a Button
so I can set the interactable via c#

here is my code

```
// Buildings
[Header("Buildings")]
public Button [] buildingTiers;
public int numOfBuildingTiers = 6; // Number of building tier buttons;

// ==============================================================
void Awake()
{
    buildingTiers = new Button[numOfBuildingTiers];

    for (var i = 1; i < numOfBuildingTiers; i++)
    {
        GameObject _buildingTiers = GameObject.Find ("Tier " + i).GetComponent<Button> (); // This is line 37
        buildingTiers [i] = _buildingTiers; // This is line 38
        buildingTiers [i].interactable = false;
    }
}
```

and I got this error

> Assets/Octa Interactive's Assets/Codes/Main.cs(37,71): error CS0029:
>   Cannot implicitly convert type `UnityEngine.UI.Button' to`
>   UnityEngine.GameObject'

and

> Assets/Octa Interactive's Assets/Codes/Main.cs(38,33): error CS0029:
>   Cannot implicitly convert type `UnityEngine.GameObject' to`
>   UnityEngine.UI.Button'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
// Buildings
[Header("Buildings")]
public Button [] buildingTiers;
public int numOfBuildingTiers = 6; // Number of building tier buttons;

// ==============================================================
void Awake()
{
    buildingTiers = new Button[numOfBuildingTiers];

    for (var i = 1; i <= numOfBuildingTiers; i++)
    {
        Button _buildingTiers = GameObject.Find ("Tier " +    i).GetComponent<Button> (); // This is line 37
        buildingTiers [i] = _buildingTiers; // This is line 38
        buildingTiers [i].interactable = false;
    }    
}
```

You were getting the **Button** component and "storing" it in a **GameObject** variable.

Also you are only adding buttons from Tier1 to Tier5, fixed that for you too. `<=` instead of `<`.